# get id of sub collection in firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure in Firestore,

```
private FirebaseFirestore db;
db.collection("abc").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("def");
```

I'm getting id of sub-collection with this piece of code

```
String subCollectionId;
subCollectionId=db.collection("abc").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("def").getId();
```

But this code is sending me back "def" string instead of id

Comment: Please add your code as formatted code. Check this link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: the ID of the subcollection is `def`, so it is correct that the second fragment returns that. What value did you expect instead?

Comment: Each of Firestore collections has an id like  (mPgp7Z8uDJS6fk6etOzEIjzIgSo2) I want to get id of  subcollection my subcollection name "def"

Comment: Please update your question with all the necessary information in order to help you with  a resonse. What documentation you followed, what is the expected behaviour ?